# Example on a divergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of: A sequence that has no convergent subsequence.

can I say $(-1)^n$?

just wanted to make sure! thanks.

Comment: No, $1,1,1,...$ is convergent, and a subsequence. A valid example is the naturals.

Comment: of course this sequence has two convergent  subsequences. just take $n$ odd and even

Comment: In fact, any bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: I meant that $(-1)^n$ oscillates that's why I thought of it. the question is asking for an example on a divergent sequence right?

Comment: You will need a sequence like $n$ or $(-1)^nn$ with absolute value tending to $\infty$.

Comment: Every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit, so yes, the example must be divergent.  But $(-1)^n$ has many convergent subsequences, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) proves that all *bounded* sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ have a converging subsequence, you should find such an example from unbounded sequences. For example,

\begin{equation}
a_n = n
\end{equation}

is a very easy and simple example.

Comment: oh! thank you so much

Comment: @raydiiii But unbounded is not enough. For example, $1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,...$ is unbounded and has the convergent subsequence $1,1,1,...$ If every subsequence must be divergent, then all subsequences must be unbounded. Therefore, the sequence's absolute value must tend to $\infty$.

Comment: @flan You misunderstood my statement. *All* bounded sequences have converging subsequences. That doesn't necessarily mean all unbounded sequences do not have converging subsequences. That is, the converse of the true statement is not necessarily true. Of course, there are infinite number of unbounded sequences that have converging subsequences!